# Additional class for objects construction when working with database

Tags: architecture, android

I have a class derived from `SQLiteOpenHelper` which is all about working with a database, i.e. tables creation, insertions, data selections. All methods which deal with data selection return a `Cursor`. What I really want is to get a list of objects rather than a `cursor`, at the same time I don't want my class to do a lot of things. Is it a good idea to add another class who get selections from a database and construct objects from the selection? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pattern you should look into is the Repository pattern. Nice example [here](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/). There will be many others out there on the web.

The Repository pattern compliments your database access and  allows you to define queries and return result items as the objects you want.

You create your domain object like User and return that object type from the repository.